# How to create custom codegen with help of Swagger 3.0.31

Tags: swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

Initially we had swagger-codegen 2.4.22 in our project. We have customized the generator as per requirement with below set of code. Which was working fine.

```
<java jar="@{baseDir}/lib/swagger-custom-codegen.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="generate"/>
      <arg line="-l de.hybris.platform.XXXXX.swagger.XXXXCodegen"/>
      <arg line="-i @{templateDir}/@{version}/@{file}"/>
      <arg line="-o @{baseDir}/gensrc/"/>
      <arg line="-c @{baseDir}/resources/swaggerconfig/@{version}/swagger-generator-config.json"/>
      <arg line="--model-package @{defaultPackage}.@{version}.dto"/>
      <arg line="--api-package @{defaultPackage}.@{version}.api"/>
</java>
```

Now we are upgrading to swagger-codegen 3.0.31 and above piece of code is failing with below error.

```
[echo] building extension 'XXXXX'...
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name de.hybris.platform.XXXXX.swagger.XXXXCodegen Available: dart

[java]     at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
[java]     at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:96)
[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class de.hybris.platform.XXXXX.swagger.XXXXCodegen  cannot be cast to class io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfig (de.hybris.platform.XXXXX.swagger.XXXXCodegen and io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfig are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
[java]     at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
[java]     ... 1 more

BUILD FAILED
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I believe the 3.x codegen cannot use custom generators built for 2.x. You'll probably need to regenerate the boilerplate for your custom generator using codegen 3.0.31 and move the implementation there and build the new JAR.